# PHP can't open downloaded zip but the file on the server is openable

Tags: php, download

I use ZipArchive to create zip file. It all works well except one thing - downloading it as attachment. When I try to open downloaded file 7-zip says : "Can't open file .... as archive". There's everything allright with the file saved on the server. When I tried to compare downloaded file with the file stored on the server there's small difference in the end of the file.

To put it simply: archive on the server opens but after downloading it it doesn't

The code I use :

```
$file='Playlist.zip';
    if (headers_sent()) {
        echo 'HTTP header already sent';
    } else {
        if (!is_file($file)) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
            echo 'File not found';
        } else if (!is_readable($file)) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
            echo 'File not readable';
        } else {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
            header("Content-Type: application/zip");
            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file)."");
            header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
            header("Expires: 0");
            set_time_limit(0);
            $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
            while (!feof($handle)){
                echo fread($handle, 8192);
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

[image: difference]

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked

put this at the beginning of the php file

```
ob_start();
```

then, after the headers and immediately before the `readfile` put this

```
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

wrapping up

```
ob_start();//this is new
$file='/path/to/Playlist.zip';
if (headers_sent()) {
   echo 'HTTP header already sent';
} else {
  if (!is_file($file)) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
    echo 'File not found';
  } else if (!is_readable($file)) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
    echo 'File not readable';
  } else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file)."");
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0");
    while (ob_get_level()) {//this is new
       ob_end_clean();//this is new
    }//this is new
  readfile($file);//this is new
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fpassthru()`:

```
$file="Playlist.zip";
if (headers_sent()) {
    echo "HTTP header already sent";
} else {
    if (!is_file($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 404 Not Found");
        echo "File not found";
    } else if (!is_readable($file)) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 403 Forbidden");
        echo "File not readable";
    } else {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . " 200 OK");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file));
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
        fpassthru($handle);
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. What is your PHP and apache version? What exactly is the small difference at the end of the file?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/zip-file-is-corrupt-after-download
ob_clean() and flush() helped me. It works now :) Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a `$data=ltrim($data)` to remove the leading blanks in the downloaded ZIP file.